# Nested loops for mongodb arrays in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nested, radio-button

Hey so I'm reasonably new to Node.js and Mongodb, I am making a roster creation system and I want to make it so that only two users/employees can work on a given shift. For simplicity the shifts are split into 'day' and 'night' which are in a table of radio buttons that the user can chosen. Onload of the shifts page however I want to disable those buttons which have already been chosen by two other users.

I think that the outer loop should iterate through the shifts array of the users (Monday --> Sunday), the inner loop should then iterate through each user in the mongodb database. Eventually I want to have the code working for each day of the week but for now just need Monday to function properly.

Thanks for any help and advise

```
function disableOnLoad() {
    console.log("disableOnLoad reached");
    var dayCount=0;           
    var nightCount=0;
    $.getJSON( '/shiftsTable', function( data ) {
        $.each(data, function(){
            userListData = data;         
        for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
            **//$.each(data, function(){**
            if(this.shifts[i]=='day'){
             if(i==0){
                dayCount++;
                console.log("dayCount: "+dayCount);  
                if(dayCount>2){document.getElementById("monDay").disabled=true;}
             }
            }
            else if(this.shifts[0]=='night'){
                nightCount++;
                if (nightCount>2){document.getElementById("monNight").disabled=true;}
            } 
            }
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: How does your shifts JSON look?

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed  An entire user object is as follows                                        {
    "_id" : ObjectId("589f60999c471a32c6a3a380"),
    "name" : "Ciara",
    "email" : "ciara@test.com",
    "company" : "Apple ",
    "username" : "Ciara",
    "password" : "$2a$10$QkaRzb7W/BOzvtnY8hPtQ.j3GWy.XI92X6osh3m4/TNEuPBrAprva",
    "position" : "Sales assistant",
    "location" : "Dublin",
    "admin" : 0,
    "shifts" : [ 
        "day", 
        "day", 
        "night", 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        "23"
    ]
  }

Comment: Looks fine to me, where are you facing a problem?

Comment: @SharjeelAhmed The above code has no effect, if I remove the "if(i==0){" statement then the code iterates through a user and checks if they have two 'days' in total in their shifts array whereas I want to iterate through all the users and check if there are two of them with 'day' in just their shifts[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the data

```
    data = [{
    "_id": "589f60999c471a32c6a3a380",
    "name": "Ciara",

    "position": "Sales assistant",
    "location": "Dublin",
    "admin": 0,
    "shifts": ["day", "day", "night", null, null, null, null, "23"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "589f60999c471a32c6a3a380",
    "name": "Ciara2",

    "position": "Sales assistant",
    "location": "Dublin",
    "admin": 0,
    "shifts": ["day", "day", "night", null, null, null, null, "23"]
  },{
    "_id": "589f60999c471a32c6a3a380",
    "name": "Ciara3",
    "position": "Sales assistant",
    "location": "Dublin",
    "admin": 0,
    "shifts": ["day", "day", "night", null, null, null, null, "23"]
  }];
```

So this code works for me

```
     $.each(data, function(val) {

    userListData = data;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { //* * //$.each(data, function(){**
      if (i==0 && this.shifts[i] == 'day') {
          dayCount++;
          if (dayCount == 2) {
            document.getElementById("monDay").disabled = true;
          }
      } else if (i==0 && this.shifts[i] == 'night') {
        nightCount++;
        if (nightCount == 2) {
          document.getElementById("monNight").disabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: That looks right to me as well however it does not work for me, irrelevant of how many days the accounts choose the buttons are never disabled

Comment: paste your html here also any error on your console?

Comment: The only places i refer to the script in the html are <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="/javascripts/shift.js"></script>
  <body onload="disableOnLoad()">

Comment: A sample of the shifts table is as follows:<form method="post" action="/shift">
    <div id="shiftsTable">
    <table class="container"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><h1>Monday</h1></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="day">
                    <div onclick="colorChanger(this);"><label><input type="radio" id="monDay" onclick="calculateTotal()" name="monday" value="day"><p class="dayText">Day </p> <p>9:00 - 17:00</p> <p class="scoreText">Points: 240</p> </label></div>
                </td>

Comment: hardcode the "data" variable as i have given above, and let me know if it works, else u need to paste the entire JSON what you get from the ajax call

Comment: _id: 589b4af0714d451fa002dec0,
  name: 'SteveTest',
  email: 'steve@test.com',
  company: 'RegTest2',
  username: 'SteveTest',
  password: '$2a$10$yG3tczaBOrirY8Y1hXJ8vujrvPI0QdI7wc./WxWKV.9v5PEb128l2',
  position: 'RegTest2',
  location: 'RegTest2',
  admin: 0,
  __v: 0,
  shifts: [ 'day', 'day', null, 'day', 'night', null, null, '31' ],
  score: [ 400, 940, 120, 50, 0 ] }

Comment: _id: 589f4fd39c471a32c6a3a37f,
  name: 'Mark',
  email: 'mark@eurogiant.com',
  company: 'Giant',
  username: 'Mark',
  password: '$2a$10$UJNMbhPoHVLPizueOkH2Se1SNXCOAnM8zc8F9nXSul7kCPYF5OdLC',
  position: 'Sales assistant',
  location: 'Dublin',
  admin: 0,
  __v: 0,
  shifts: [ 'day', 'day', 'day', null, 'day', null, null, '32' ],
  score: [ 360, 950, 370, 350, 0 ] }  There are several other accounts but thats what two entire ones look like, thanks again for your continued help @SharjeelAhmed

Comment: Hey, yeah your example works perfectly for me in jsfiddle however it wont work in my actual code, its really quite frustrating. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: can do put console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) after  $.each(data, function(val) { and let me know what you get. Want to give this a final try

Comment: Thanks for the continued support, when I add that line nothing prints out. The shift.js file is accessed but nothing prints in the console log relating to the data

Comment: var studentListData = [];
 var shiftArray = new Array();
    shiftArray[0]=8;
    shiftArray[1]=7;
$(document).ready(function() {
    populateTable();
    $('#studentList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkshowstudent', showStudentInfo);
  var data = db.getCollection("users")
  var dayCount=0;
  var nightCount=0;  
    $.each(data, function(val) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    studentListData = data;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
      if (i==0 && this.shifts[i] == 'day') {
          dayCount++;

Comment: if (dayCount == 2) {document.getElementById("monDay").disabled = true;}
      } else if (i==0 && this.shifts[i] == 'night') {
        nightCount++;
        if (nightCount == 2) {
          document.getElementById("monNight").disabled = true;}}}});});

Comment: Thats what my current shifts.js file looks like and then there are a few extra functions at the bottom of the file outside of the scope of $(document).ready(function() {}

Comment: That means "data" is empty  and you are not receiving any data from your ajax

Comment: That means "data" is empty  and you are not receiving any data from your ajax. Infact you should put console.log(data) BEFORE the $.each, not after, try that

Comment: Still nothing prints, should I be making a connection to the mongodb database in shifts.js because var data = db.getCollection("users") is not getting any data?

Comment: In my routes file the table is already connected to my shifts table  : router.get('/shiftsTable', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('users').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});

Comment: do a console.log(items) before res.json, if it is empty mostly you have to do a mongo connect, but I suggest you use mongoose npm.

Comment: So items is an array of objects which i believe is correct-- [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] --- also i am using mongoose but its most likely poorly integrated

Comment: You need to convert the mongoose object to JSON http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952649/convert-mongoose-docs-to-json

Comment: To update you, i have been trying to stringify the repsonse but with no luck, db.collection('users').find().lean().exec(function (err, items) {
        return res.end(JSON.stringify(items));
    });

Comment: so is it empty? Also i see that you are using mongoDB driver not mongoose, not sure if that has the lean() method, you may have to use toArray()