# How to fetch data from express and MongoDB to be read with d3.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, d3.js, mongoose

Basically, I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB collection and read it with `d3.json`.

First, I sent data to a specific route in main `index.js`.

```
// fetch data
app.get('/fetch.json', (req, res) => {
  Data.find({})
    .then(sample => {
      res.json(sample)
    })
})
```

If I check `localhost:3000/fetch.json`, my `data` is in there as an array with each object.

```
[{...},{...},{...},{...}]
```

However, when I tried to read data with `d3`, I got a `Syntax Error`:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
```

This is the code that attempts to read data:

```
// load data
d3.json('./fetch.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  data.map((t) => {
    console.log(t)
  })
})
```

I tried different approaches, considering this answer: [Convert Mongoose docs to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952649/convert-mongoose-docs-to-json). However, I got the same result.

Am I missing something inside main `index.js` or I need to fetch data in a different way?

Comment: Your request says `d3.json('./fetch.json'` and likely should be `d3.json('/fetch.json'` or whatever the "full path" to the resource really is rather than preceding with a "dot" `.`. The `Unexpected token T` message is basically the first letter of the phrase `The requested resource was not found` or essentially a `404` error. In breif, check your browser network requests and you will see the `404`. So fix the path to where the resource actually is.

Comment: @NeilLunn Is a different question and the "dot" doesn't create conflict. The "dot" means `current directory`, so the path doesn't need to be fix. I already did tests with different approaches. The problem, for I can understand, is with `d3` new versions installed with npm, and using `require('d3'`). This problem doesn't show up using normal `<script...>` on html file.

Comment: Point is that you have a `404`, hence the JSON parse error. I had the d3 docs up a moment ago, but the basics are it's just an XHTTP request that "chains" a `JSON.parse` before returning the data. Check your network tab in your browser debugging. The resource will not be found, so you need to point it to wherever the correct location is. That's the cause and that's the fix. And yes we do understand "relative" to "absolute" paths and what they mean. But a `404` "is what it is" regardless of where you "think" the endpoint is located.

Comment: I have tried with local files using the exactly path. Why jsonfile is read when I use normal `<script src="d3...>`, even `'./fetch'`, and not when I use require('d3')?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question and therefore looking in the wrong place. Go and actually look at your network requests in the browser dev tools like I told you. The JSON parse error if from exactly the string response I have told you. Work out how to talk to your backend and then you will resolve the issue.