# Get value in Object of Mongoose result

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I've query like this `const result = await Form.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });`
And here is the result of my query:

```
{ _id: 5a8ea110d7371b7e5040d5c9,
  _user: 5a5c277f8d82ba3644b971c2,
  formDate: 2018-02-22T10:53:04.579Z,
  formElement: 
   { formName: 'Vanilla Form',
     pixel: '23423325',
     fieldRows: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  formStyle: 
   { globalColor: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     elementSizing: 'medium',
     elementStyle: 'radius',
     fontFace: 'Open Sans',
     fontSize: { label: '15', button: '15' } },
  __v: 0,
  status: true }
```

I'm trying to get pixel like this `console.log(result.formElement.pixel)` 
But, when i trying to get the value of pixel, it return `undefined`.
What's wrong?

**Update**
Here is my code:

```
app.get("/view/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const result = await Form.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.formDate); //return 2018-02-22T10:53:04.579Z,
    console.log(result.formElement.pixel) //return undefined
    // res.render("form", {
    //  result
    // });
});
```

I've try to edit my code without using async instead using Promise, but it also return undefined

Comment: Debug result.formElement.formName and without async await.

Comment: Return `TypeError: Cannot read property 'formName' of undefined` @StoychoTrenchev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use **exec()** function, It returns promise.

```
app.get("/view/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let result = await Form.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).exec();
    result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.formDate); //return 2018-02-22T10:53:04.579Z,
    console.log(result.formElement.pixel) //return 23423325
    // res.render("form", {
    //  result
    // });
});
```

Comment: Still return UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pixel' of undefined

Comment: result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)) try this.

Comment: It work! Can you explain to me why I need to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))` ?

Comment: mongoose return docs by default. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952649/convert-mongoose-docs-to-json

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna need to do some digging here. Add some more console.logs to debug what is actually going on. For starters, I'd recommend printing out result to see what it actually is. My first guess is that you're trying to print result before the await finishes? I'm not sure, as I don't know exactly when you're trying to print anything out without seeing your code.