# node asyn await with for loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

```js
const cons = await Contact.find(where);
const cons2 = await countContracts(cons);
res.send(cons2);

async function countContracts(cons) {
  for (let i = 0; i < cons.length; i++) {
    cons[i].noOfContracts = await Contract.countDocuments({
      contactId: cons[i]._id,
    });
  }
  return cons;
}
```

I didn't get noOfContracts in the array of objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Mongoose docs to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952649/convert-mongoose-docs-to-json). TL;DR use `Contact.find(where).lean()` to work with plain JS objects instead of Mongoose Documents

Comment: no I want to loop through mongoose documents

Comment: You're not understanding. Adding extra properties like `noOfContracts` onto documents won't be serialised to JSON when you send the response. If you want to add properties, work with plain objects